# OpenPoseのビルド時にerror: identifier "nullptr" is undefinedのエラーが発生する。

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

OpenPoseのビルド時に以下のようなエラーが発生する。

```
my@PC:~/openpose/build$ make -j`nproc`

Scanning dependencies of target openpose_caffe
[ 12%] Creating directories for 'openpose_caffe'
[ 25%] No download step for 'openpose_caffe'
[ 37%] [ 50%] No patch step for 'openpose_caffe'
No update step for 'openpose_caffe'
[ 62%] Performing configure step for 'openpose_caffe'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   filesystem
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found GFlags: /usr/include  
-- Found gflags  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so)
-- Found Glog: /usr/include  
-- Found glog    (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so)
-- Found PROTOBUF: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so  
-- Found PROTOBUF Compiler: /usr/bin/protoc
-- Found HDF5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so  
-- CUDA detected: 8.0
-- Found cuDNN: ver. 5.1.10 found (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so)
-- Automatic GPU detection failed. Building for all known architectures.
-- Added CUDA NVCC flags for: sm_30 sm_35 sm_50 sm_52 sm_60 sm_61
-- Found Atlas: /usr/include  
-- Found Atlas (include: /usr/include library: /usr/lib/libatlas.so lapack: /usr/lib/liblapack.so
-- Python interface is disabled or not all required dependencies found. Building without it...
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "1.9.1") 
-- 
-- ******************* Caffe Configuration Summary *******************
-- General:
--   Version           :   1.0.0
--   Git               :   1.0-141-g974172c
--   System            :   Linux
--   C++ compiler      :   /usr/bin/c++
--   Release CXX flags :   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -Wall -std=c++11 -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Debug CXX flags   :   -g -fPIC -Wall -std=c++11 -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Build type        :   Release
-- 
--   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS :   ON
--   BUILD_python      :   OFF
--   BUILD_matlab      :   OFF
--   BUILD_docs        :   OFF
--   CPU_ONLY          :   OFF
--   USE_OPENCV        :   OFF
--   USE_LEVELDB       :   OFF
--   USE_LMDB          :   OFF
--   USE_NCCL          :   OFF
--   ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK :   OFF
--   USE_HDF5          :   ON
-- 
-- Dependencies:
--   BLAS              :   Yes (Atlas)
--   Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.54)
--   glog              :   Yes
--   gflags            :   Yes
--   protobuf          :   Yes (ver. 2.5.0)
--   CUDA              :   Yes (ver. 8.0)
-- 
-- NVIDIA CUDA:
--   Target GPU(s)     :   Auto
--   GPU arch(s)       :   sm_30 sm_35 sm_50 sm_52 sm_60 sm_61
--   cuDNN             :   Yes (ver. 5.1.10)
-- 
-- Install:
--   Install path      :   /home/miyo/openpose/build/caffe
-- 
CMake Warning (dev) in src/caffe/CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0022 is not set: INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES defines the link
  interface.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0022" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "caffe" has an INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property which differs from
  its LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES properties.

  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES:

    caffeproto;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so;$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so>;$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so>;-lpthread;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so;/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcurand.so;/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcublas.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so;/usr/lib/liblapack.so;/usr/lib/libcblas.so;/usr/lib/libatlas.so

  LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES:

    caffeproto;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so;-lpthread;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so;/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so;/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcurand.so;/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcublas.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so;/usr/lib/liblapack.so;/usr/lib/libcblas.so;/usr/lib/libatlas.so

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/miyo/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_caffe-build
[ 75%] Performing build step for 'openpose_caffe'
[  1%] Running C++/Python protocol buffer compiler on /home/miyo/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
Scanning dependencies of target caffeproto
[  1%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffeproto.dir/__/__/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libcaffeproto.a
[  1%] Built target caffeproto
[  1%] [  1%] [  2%] [  2%] [  4%] [  5%] [  6%] [  6%] [  6%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/solvers/./cuda_compile_generated_sgd_solver.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o
[  6%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/solvers/./cuda_compile_generated_adam_solver.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_deconv_layer.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_im2col.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/solvers/./cuda_compile_generated_adagrad_solver.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/solvers/./cuda_compile_generated_rmsprop_solver.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/solvers/./cuda_compile_generated_nesterov_solver.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/solvers/./cuda_compile_generated_adadelta_solver.cu.o
[  8%] [  8%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_lrn_layer.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_hdf5_data_layer.cu.o
Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_cudnn_sigmoid_layer.cu.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stddef.h(432): error: identifier "nullptr" is undefined

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stddef.h(432): error: expected a ";"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stddef.h(432): error: identifier "nullptr" is undefined

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stddef.h(432): error: expected a ";"


...


/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(202): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(202): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(221): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(221): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(221): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(240): error: inline specifier allowed on function declarations only

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(240): error: variable "std::constexpr" has already been defined

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath(240): error: expected a ";"

Error limit reached.
100 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00001d71_00000000-17_math_functions.compute_61.cpp1.ii".
Compilation terminated.
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o.cmake:264 (message):
  Error generating file
  /home/miyo/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_caffe-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o


make[5]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [caffe/src/openpose_caffe-stamp/openpose_caffe-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_caffe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

問題の解決方法を教えてください。

Ubuntu / 14.04
Cuda / 8.0
cudnn / 5.1
gcc / 4.9
g++ / 4.9

#### 追記

こちらにマルチポストしています

- https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/issues/981
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880164/when-i-try-make-i-get-error-identifier-nullptr-is-undefined

githubで教えて頂いた解決法として以下のコードを試したが、問題は解決できませんでした。

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

#### 追記２

```
my@PC:~$ cc --version
cc (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.9.4
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

my@PC:~$ c++ --version
c++ (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.9.4
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: ちなみに、Ubuntu 14.04 や g++ 4.9 という条件は変えられないのでしょうか？ [Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS の End of Life は 2019 年 4 月](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)なのですが……。(ただ、OpenPose の対応 OS の中で Ubuntu は 14 と 16 だけが挙げられているようですね)

Comment: ``make -j`nproc` `` とあるのは、`nproc` に適切な数をあてて実行したわけではなく、そのまま実行なさったのでしょうか？　（ここが原因ではない気がしますが、一応の確認です。）

Comment: @nekketsuuu OpenPose の対応OSの問題もあるのですが、現在使用しているのが共同で使用しているサーバーであるため、OSの変更は難しそうです、、申し訳ございません。

Comment: @nekketsuuu そのまま実行していました、　ただ、"-j`nproc`"なしでの "make all" でも同様のエラーが得られました。

Comment: `c++11`が有効されていないと考えています。私のほうOS環境が16の場合、そういうエラーが出ませんでした。